# This folder(every folder in C drive) is empty after WIN10 update. But it occupies several hundred GB

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-update, file-recovery, hidden-file

After win10 update on last Friday, my computer didn't turn off, so I turned it off. After rebooting, the below line on the black screen occurred, it says fixing HDD some %, eventually it was checking over 100%. I turned it off and checked the HDD by several thankful advices from youtube and google users over 3 days.

But the problem is still unsolved.
(I wonder why only the Stock program folder files are still remaining)

●My pc situation ●

1. Most Top folders are remaining.
2. Most sub folders and files are disappeared except a few useless folders.
3. Only a Stock exchange program folder is alive. I can see the files
4. I see $SysReset folder with the malfunction date.
   ...

Anybody help me please. ...

■Things I'd done over 3 days■

1. virus check advised by MS

   v3, bitdefender, and a few other vaccine programs

   Result: It's clean
2. Bad sector check

   All green
3. `chkdsk`

   the final response: unidentified errors occurred!
4. `attrib -h -r -s /s /d h:\*.*`

   access denied
5. Windows error check

   Result: Can't recover the drive
6. HDD SCAN with a program

   All green
7. hidden file option check

   No good
8. I tried to recover at least excel files with several recovery programs. But it failed. (Recovered some files but no good)

.....

What else can I do?
plz help me.....

Comment: This can be a problem with NTFS file permissions. Using an administrator account take over ownership of that folder and grant everybody full control for this folder and all subfolder and files.

Comment: You talk about a folder but don't indicate what folder you are referring to.

Comment: The EVERY FOLDERS(except a stock program folder) IN C DRIVE.

Comment: Do you mean that every single folder on your drive is empty? Can you just not see the files inside them? You also don't state what the problem is now. You saw that the scan process completed, but then you just shut it off. Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Make sure your backups are up to date

You have backups, right? You should, because your software and hardware won't give you a courteous warning before failing.

If you don't, copy all your important data to external storage **now**.

## 2. Check if the disk is healthy

It seems that your filesystem is corrupted. This should not happen under normal circumstances. One possible explanation would be that your drive is failing.

Check SMART parameters. Focus on *pending sectors* and *reallocated sectors*. Both should have the raw value of 0. If they are different than 0, it means the drive has noticed some problems and is trying to fix them (and apparently it's not successful). Such drives can get worse anytime and shouldn't be used to store any important files.

## 3. Format the drive

Fixing a filesystem corrupted so badly `chkdsk` doesn't want to touch it is not feasible. You'll have to create a new one, ie. format the drive. This implies wiping all your files (and Windows, if it's the system partition). You can restore them from backups afterwards.

If you've determined that the drive is failing in the previous step, you may be tempted to clone the old drive to the replacement. Don't do that. Corrupted filesystems can't be cloned reliably.

Comment: Drive `H:` is not the system disk. I think you should counsel backup+format+restore, rather than Windows reinstallation.

Comment: @harrymc Good point, I've reworded that part.

Comment: I took it apart from pc and put it in a usb style docking box to avoid restarting automatic  " fixing Hdd ~~~"